# RabbitMQ - How to deal with rest queues

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

Hi I am working on RabbitMQ integration. I have a problem to deal with queues - If Q1 is processing and it is taking time then how can i process another queue in between?

Comment: What do you mean with a queue is processing? Queues are 'dumb pipes'. If your application is busy, and you want more, you need to look at workers.

Comment: I mean to say i have one process in queue and it is taking so much time, as a result another process ( which is in queue ) is not executing

Comment: I think it is sequential processing - I want process to execute parallely

Comment: Yeah, but your problem is not with RabbitMQ, it's with your processor that can't do the messages quick enough. Right?

Comment: Yes I am calling third party API's in each process so some processes executes fast and some are slow. So if one process is slow then next process should execute

Comment: Exactly.. you need multiple processes.

Comment: Yes I am processing multiple processes in single queue - I mean processes P1, P2, P3, P4 will be in queue named "RPC_QUEUE" and i want to execute all these processes parallely

Comment: Then get 4 workers/processors/scripts that all get a message from the queue. RabbitMQ can easily throw out 3000 msg/s, it's just up to your consumers to do the hard work.

Comment: yes but if first message takes time then second message have to wait for the first message to execute, that's what i don't want. If 1st message is taking a time then 2nd message should execute

Comment: How many scripts do you have that are working on stuff in the queue? If the answer is 1, then how would a second thing from the queue get processed while that 1 worker is already busy? You need to have 2 or more workers. Do you?

Comment: I am having a single script which handles all processing. All messages are in the queue named "RPC_QUEUE". As said earlier, if one message is processing then 2nd message will have to wait. What's the solution for this? Do i need to run different script for the same queue which process two messages parallely.

Comment: That's what everyone's been trying to tell you. Having only a single worker working on a queue means only a single job can be done at a time. If you want jobs to be done in parallel, have multiple workers work on the same queue.